# Salesforce @RemoteAction not redirecting the VF page

Tags: customer-community, salesforce-id, remote-action

We are using angular js & jquery in Custom SelfRegistration VF page for Community , in Controller side @RemoteAction is in use and redirection of page after user creation is working fine from VF as below:

```
 //method to redirect page after successful registration.
   $scope.redirectToLogin = function()
  {
   $window.location.href = '{!JSENCODE($Site.BaseUrl)}/RegistrationConfirm';    

    }
```

**Button Code:**

```
 <div id="saveContinue">
  <input type="button" class="req-doc-btn" value="SAVE AND CONTINUE" ng-click="createCommunityUser();"/>
  </div>
```

where Registration confirmation is a static page. We are replacing the page to another dynamic page which holds user session just after the user registration but this is distorting the CSS and user session is not there.
Now trying to handle this from Controller (@RemoteAction) after commenting VF href call.
**Controller snippet:**

```
   if(registrationForm.password!=null && registrationForm.password.length()> 1){                      
          System.debug('$$$ Password is not Null---->'+registrationForm.password);
         return Site.login(registrationForm.email, registrationForm.password, '/apex/InformationPage');          
                 }
                else{     // Confirmation Page.
                    System.debug('$$$ Password is Null gng to call Confirmation page---->');

       page = System.Page.RegistrationConfirm;
       page.setRedirect(true);
       return page;

      }
```

The above controller code is working for normal VF page using command button, seems something causing an issue because of the @RemoteAction.
Please Suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RemoteAction functions cannot automtically redirect a user. Consider using an apex:actionFunction instead:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="createCommunityUser" action="{!createCommunityUser}" reRender="form" />
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for prompt response. We are using angular so in button section javacsript is called where Userdetail is sent to the controller via RemoteAction. <input type="button" class="req-doc-btn" value="SAVE AND CONTINUE" ng-click="createCommunityUser();"/>                                              If using <apex:actionFunction> I need to pass userdetail parameters in action method which will change the entire code. Trying to find how we can use both angular js and actionFunction. With Vf tags apex:function will work fine but I need with angular. Hope I have explained my issue here.

Comment: @HRZ If you use a RemoteAction, **your Angular controller** must check the return value from the called method and take appropriate action. If you use an actionFunction, the system will do so for you. It's your choice, as both alternatives will require additional coding.